# Cutting dendrogram at highest level of purity

Tags: data-mining, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to create program that cluster documents using hierarchical agglomerative clustering, and the output of the program depends on cutting the dendrogram at such a level that I get maximum purity.

So following is the algorithm I am working on right now.

```
Create dedrogram for the documents in the dataset
purity = 0
final_clusters
for all the levels, lvl, in the dendrogram
    clusters = cut dendrogram at lvl
    new_purity = calculate_purity_of(clusters)
    if new_purity > purity
        purity = new_purity
        final_clusters = clusters
```

according to this algorithm I get the clusters at which the purity calculated is highest at all the levels.

The problem is, when I cut the dendrogram at lowest level, every cluster contains only one document, which means it is 100% pure, therefore average purity of clusters is 1.0. But this is not the desired output. What I want is proper grouping of documents. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a too simple measure.

Yes, the "optimal" solution with respect to purity is to only merge duplicate objects, so that each cluster remains pure by definition.

This is why optimizing a mathematical criterion often isn't the right approach to tackle a real data problem. Instead, you need to ask yourself the question: "what would be an *interesting* result", where interesting is not the same as optimal in a mathematical sense.

Sorry that I cannot give you a better answer - but I don't have your data.

IMHO, any abstract mathematical approach will suffer from the same fate. You need to have your *data* and *user needs* specify what to cluster, not some statistical number; so don't look in mathematics for the answer, but look at your data and your user needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few years, but one potential way you can improve your results is to add a penalty component that increases with the number of clusters. That way, your "optimal setting" doesn't take the shortcut and instead gives you a more balanced solution.